# How to unlock an Iphone if you forgot your passcode

Tags: iphone

If I forgot my passcode because I was in boot camp how do I unlock my phone without restarting everything and losing all my information, numbers, et....?

Comment: How to unlock a door without having the key and breaking the door or lock?

Comment: What does bootcamp have to do with your phone's password?

Answer (score 1):

You can try attaching your device to the first synced computer that will give u unlimited chances to enter your pass

Or you can Just restore an old backup

If none of this work you should have used iCloud for contacts